# How to calculate the approximate gradient of a series of points?

Tags: algorithms

The situation is this: a series of points are randomly located, a line is needed to represent the gradient of those points.

```
  ./ 
  /  .
```

.  /
   ./
   /  .

I am a programmer but not math expert, I need the method to find such a line. Can anyone give me some direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique called "least squares linear fit." Those keywords should help you find a discussion in a textbook or on the web.

Comment: Cool, this looks like what I need, thanks a lot!

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" the answer, by clicking in the check mark next to it.